# Getting 'The timestampsInSnapshots setting now defaults to true' firestore error in console

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting the following error from Firestore in console, in Angular.

@firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.8.3): 
  The timestampsInSnapshots setting now defaults to true and you no
  longer need to explicitly set it. In a future release, the setting
  will be removed entirely and so it is recommended that you remove it
  from your firestore.settings() call now.

Any suggestions, how to get rid of it?

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning.  What exactly is your firestore.setting() call that it's asking you about?

Comment: @DougStevenson Basically, it appears as an error, instead of a warning. I am not calling firestore.setting() anywhere.

Comment: Then just ignore it.

Comment: Looks bad on console.

Comment: Do your users look at the console?  Does it affect the way your code executes?

Comment: Users do not see it, but people in the team question about the console error? Warning would have been better, instead of 'red' error

Comment: Feel free to file a bug report if you don't like the way the SDK works.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Comment: Okay! Thanks! I will

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Go to your app.modules.ts file and add import:

```
import { FirestoreSettingsToken} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```

Then add this value in your providers array:

```
providers: [{ provide: FirestoreSettingsToken, useValue: {} }]
```

Comment: this seems to work for everyone but i still see the error... is this correct? `providers: [ { provide: FirestoreSettingsToken, useValue: {} }, { provide: 'SnotifyToastConfig', useValue: ToastDefaults}]`

Answer (score 3):

In general, we configure firebase in our app in the following way:

```
firebase.firestore().settings({
    timestampsInSnapshots: true
});
```

For the above configuration, It shows the following warning:

[image: @firebase/firestore: Firestore (6.3.5): The timestampsInSnapshots setting now defaults to true and you no longer need to explicitly set it. In a future release, the setting will be removed entirely and so it is recommended that you remove it from your firestore.settings() call now.]

In Order to resolve it, Just simply remove the **`timestampsInSnapshots`** attribute from the **`settings`** parameter. After fixing, your config should be changed to:

```
firebase.firestore().settings({});
```

Comment: May I ask what is the purpose of `timestampsInSnapshots`, I forgot what it is doing and I can no longer find a documentation about it. I guess it was now removed.